# Jaydata Planet example throwing DefaultError: DEFAULT ERROR CALLBACK

Tags: javascript, jaydata

I am trying to run planets example of JayData, but when I am trying to load html file on browser it gives me error on firebug saying:

> DefaultError: DEFAULT ERROR CALLBACK!

I checked inside jaydata.js(1.2.5) at line where error is thrown and it comes in function Guard.raise where it checks for intellisense object whether its undefined or not. I tried searching for its declaration but not able to, could you help me to solve this problem and where can I get this intellisense object?

Thanks,
Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses sqlite to store data. It works with chrome because chrome does support sqlite but it does not work with firefox for example.. Which browser did you try ?
We have a virtual provider called 'local' which hides the different storages that the different browsers support.
We only have to change sqlite to local and it will work in all browsers...

Comment: Thanks a lot...LocalStorage worked on firefox, and other on chrome